# Process for account suspension?

Tags: discussion

Looking at the user page of [carlo-r](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/271/carlo-r), I can see that his account was suspended and reputation set to 1. I can see only [a single question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/896/130), closed and with votes +3/-3; safe to say it's controversial, but I personally disagree that it's *just flame-bait*, as commented by moderator Shog9♦. Is account suspension a community decision or an act single-handedly by a moderator? Is there any more specific reason than *because of low-quality contributions*? The suspension notice links to a 2009 blog post specifying a number of possible reasons. Do those apply to the Marxism question, or to other contributions that I can't see right now?

Comment: I think the displayed reason sums it up pretty well, but just to clarify: there's a lot more in that account that you *can't* see.

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking, suspensions are the moderators' last line of defence against a user who repeatedly abused the site in one way or another. Users don't get suspended for a single bad question, you can safely assume that the user has posted a series of equally crappy (or worse) questions.

You will not get more information on the suspension than the sort blurb and the blog post. It's a private matter and moderators (that we don't have yet) and Stack Exchange employees are bound by the [moderator agreement](https://politics.stackexchange.com/legal/moderator-agreement) and can't discuss private matters in public. If the suspended user wishes to discuss their suspension in public, they can post a Meta question about it when their suspension ends.

Lastly, if you feel the question was incorrectly closed, feel free to vote to re-open it. Personally, I think it's exactly the type of question we should avoid on Politics. Its possibly controversial nature doesn't bother me that much, but it's extremely vague and open ended, and there is absolutely no sign of prior research.

Comment: +1, including the last paragraph. I am not fully onboard with Shog9's wording of "flamebait", but I did DV and VTC due to poor quality of the question in StackExchange format. Too vague and open-ended, to steal Yannis' words.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a moderator here but I can answer some of your doubts.

1. Suspension is a moderator-only action. This doesn't necessarily make it single-handedly, though. Many times we consult other moderators or our fellow moderators to receive some feedback. If we're sure, we might just do it.

   In this case, a team member did it, so I doubt there is abuse.

   Anyway, it's not possible to abuse of this, because moderator actions can be checked by the Team and if some abuse happens they'll know about it. (In the future, if you think a mod abused their position, just email the team providing as much info as you can about the case).
2. It's not possible to know more details about suspensions than what you already know from the in-profile notice. The suspended user is free to share any detail they want about the suspension and probably moderators would contribute there too, but moderators *cannot* share any details if the users didn't in the first place. It's in our Agreement: we cannot share details that are available to us thanks to our position. This is for privacy matters, of course. The only one that can violate this is the suspended user him/herself.

So, yeah, you're not going to receive anymore detail than you already know.